# How to remove zoom effect from bootstrap carousel with captions?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, carousel

I figured out that bootstrap carousel with captions has zoom effect. I need captions but i do not need zoom. Can someone help? I googled the issue but was not able to find the answer.

```html
<div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide"
     data-bs-ride="carousel">

  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="img/aloyan.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>Dr. Hayk Aloyan</h5>
        <p>President and Non-Executive Director of Mineral Investment Group</p>


      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>Mr. Hovhannes Karapetyan</h5>
        <p>COO, founder of Mountain Jaguar Team</p>
      </div>
      <img src="img/karapetyan.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">

    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="img/megrelidze.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>Mr. Giorgi Megrelidze</h5>
        <p> Managing Director, founder of Mountain Jaguar Team</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button"
     data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button"
     data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: The default Bootstrap carousel does not zoom images. Have you copied CSS from somewhere else, like this codepen: [Botstrap Carousel Zoom Effect](https://codepen.io/altafhpatel/pen/JWGxBq)?

Answer (score 0):

Just check on which class is the css command "transform: scale" or eq an erase it in the css file. For more help we need to get an working example.

Comment: I dont know how to find bootstrap commands. There is no transform command in my css file

Comment: without your css file its hard to say why it is zooming. You know the inspector tool in browsers by pressing f12? Perhaps that will help you to find the correct css class.